# cardinal addition theorems

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> A cardinal number $\alpha$ is a number such that there exists a set $A$ so that $|A| = \alpha.$ The sum of two cardinal numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is given by $\alpha + \beta := |A\cup B|,$ where $A$ and $B$ are sets so that $ A\cap B = \emptyset, |A| = \alpha, |B| = \beta$.

> Let $\alpha, \beta,$ and $\gamma $ be cardinal numbers. Prove that

- $\alpha + \beta$ is well defined.
- $\alpha + \beta = \beta + \alpha$ and $(\alpha + \beta) + \gamma = \alpha + (\beta + \gamma).$

To show the first property, it suffices to show that for any sets $A,B,C,D$ with $|A| = |C|, |B| = |D|, A\cap B = C\cap D = \emptyset, |A\cup B| = |C\cup D|.$ Since the sets are disjoint, by the properties of union (for any sets, including infinite ones), $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| = |C| + |D| = |C\cup D| = \alpha + \beta.$

The property that $\alpha + \beta = \beta + \alpha$ seems to follow for commutativity of $\cup$: for any two sets $A, B, |A\cup B| = |B\cup A|.$ $\alpha + \beta := |A\cup B|,$ where $A\cap B = \emptyset, |A| = \alpha$ and $|B| = \beta.$ And $\beta + \alpha = |B\cup A| = |A\cup B| = \alpha + \beta.$

The second property seems to follow from associativity of union. $(\alpha + \beta) + \gamma = |(A_1\cup A_2)\cup A_3|, A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for $i\neq j, |A_1| = \alpha, |A_2| = \beta, |A_3| = \gamma.$ Since the $A_i$'s are disjoint, $\alpha + (\beta + \gamma) = |A_1 \cup (A_2 \cup A_3)|$ and by associativity of union, $\alpha + (\beta + \gamma) = |A_1 \cup (A_2 \cup A_3)| =  |(A_1\cup A_2)\cup A_3| = (\alpha + \beta) + \gamma.$

> Is this correct?

Comment: I would edit in your definition of cardinals, as I suspect your definition differs from mine.

Comment: @DonThousand I'll do that. thanks

Comment: If well-definedness of $+$ is under question, you cannot use $+$ in your proof. (E.g. $|A|+|B|$ has no meaning unless you prove that $+$ is well-defined.) You are advised to start from the definition what $|A|=|C|$ means (there is a bijection $f:A\to C$). Similarly, there is a bijection $g:B\to D$. If $A\cap B=\emptyset, C\cap D=\emptyset$, try proving that you can then make a bijection $h:A\cup B\to C\cup D$.

Comment: @FredJefferson Your definition doesn't make sense to me. What do you mean by "number"? What is the $||$ operation?

Comment: @DonThousand - They are only giving a summarized version of the definition of cardinals and cardinality, not a full-blown description, which would require many pages and a deep delve into hard set theory to do adequately. As long as you don't resort to simple induction (transfinite induction is okay), you can pretend we are talking about Natural numbers and finite sets only. $|A|$ is the number of elements in $A$.